# Using fmap with a maybe when a function uses IO

Tags: haskell

I have a function that I want to use a `Maybe` val with. Usually I would do `func <$> val`. But now suppose that `func` uses the IO monad. `func <$> val` will return a `Maybe (IO ())`. So instead I had to define a new operator:

```
(<$$>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> Maybe a -> m ()
(<$$>) func (Just val) = func val >> return ()
(<$$>) func Nothing    = return ()
```

So now I can write `func <$$> val`, but is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

`mapM_` from [`Data.Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html) is probably the best match:

```
Prelude Data.Foldable> :set -XScopedTypeVariables
Prelude Data.Foldable> :t \f (a :: Maybe a) -> Data.Foldable.mapM_ f a
\f (a :: Maybe a) -> Data.Foldable.mapM_ f a
  :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> Maybe a -> m ()
```

If you'd like a more specialised type there's also `maybe`:

```
Prelude> :t \f -> maybe (return ()) (f $)
\f -> maybe (return ()) (f $)
  :: Monad m => (a -> m ()) -> Maybe a -> m ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `<$$>` is [`traverse_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v%3atraverse-95-) from `Data.Foldable`.

Answer (score 0):

Is a one-liner always better? Here's how purity of `undefined` can be useful:

```
(<$$>) g x = maybe (return undefined) g x >> return ()
```

Example:

```
 Prelude> print <$$> (Just 1)
 1
 Prelude> print <$$> Nothing
 Prelude>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of this in your code, it might be worth employing the [`MaybeT` transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html#v%3aMaybeT):

```
   (\func val -> liftIO . func =<< MaybeT (return val) ) 
        :: (a -> IO b) -> Maybe b -> MaybeT IO b
```

That doesn't immediately bring you any further than plain `IO (Maybe ())`, but it composes nicely.